# HTML redirection script help needed to modify to show the redirection url instead of redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, dom-events

This is the script:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT type="javascript">
        function goToPage(var url = '')
        {
        var initial = "http://www.blossompromotions.com/-p-";
        var extension = "html";
        
        window.location(initial+url+extension);
        }
        </SCRIPT>
        <TITLE>Redirect 1</TITLE>
        <BASE HREF="http://www.blossompromotions.com/">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <P></P>
        <FORM name="something" action="#">Label 
            <INPUT type="text" name="url" value="" onSubmit="goToPage(this.value)" />
            <INPUT type="submit" value="GO" />
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This redirects to the url but I want the user to be able to see and copy the url. Please tell a command instead of `goToPage` which will display the url on screen for the user to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function goToPage(url){
var initial = "http://www.blossompromotions.com/-p-";
var extension = ".html";
var link = document.getElementById('gotoURL');
link.innerHTML = url ? initial+url+extension : '' ;
link.href = initial+url+extension;
}
```

```html
<FORM name="something" action="#">
Label 
<INPUT type="text" name="url" value="" onkeyup="goToPage(this.value)">
<INPUT type="submit" value="GO">
</FORM>
<a href="" id="gotoURL"></a>
```

Comment: thanks a lot but only one issue, how will user be able to copy this url?

Comment: Thats upto you, use some modal plugin to show url or have another input box or span to hold the url and show it. Check updated answer

Comment: I am a newbie, there's no command for displaying a form input like that?

Comment: Wow Man You're Awesome :) thanks a lot, worked like a charm

Comment: can u tell how can I make the text of span hyperlinked or clickable?

Comment: updated check.. but now try to do on you own.. learn by more practicing

Comment: For starter, use www.w3schools.com

Comment: bro I am unable to append the value of gotoURL into a share button: <a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="Take a look at this awesome website:" data-href="" Share</a>   I tried everything I could but it just displays gotoURL instead of showing the value. I want it to be: whatsapp://send" data-text="gotoURL"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641181/html-gotourl-issue  link of new question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with JavaScript, and add an ID to your input text

```
function goToPage(var url = '')
{
var initial = "http://www.blossompromotions.com/-p-";
var extension = "html";

document.getElementById('url').value=initial+url+extension ; 
}

<FORM name="something" action="#">
Label 
    <INPUT id="url" type="text" name="url" value="" onSubmit="goToPage(this.value)">
    <INPUT type="submit" value="GO">
</FORM>
```

Comment: can u please tell a command instead of goToPage by which user can see the url printed on his screen?