# HTML gotoURL issue

Tags: html

```
function goToPage(url){
var initial = "http://www.blossompromotions.com/-p-";
var extension = ".html";
var link = document.getElementById('gotoURL');
link.innerHTML = url ? initial+url+extension : '' ;
link.href = initial+url+extension;
}
<FORM name="something" action="#">
Label 
<INPUT type="text" name="url" value="" onkeyup="goToPage(this.value)">
<INPUT type="submit" value="GO">
</FORM>
<a href="" id="gotoURL"></a>
```

I want to create a share button for whatsapp which is:
a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="Take a look at this awesome website: ***value of gotoURL***" data-href=""Share

I can't figure out a way to do that, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function goToPage(url){
var initial = "http://xxxx.com/aff_c?offer_id=36&aff_id=1088&source=";
var extension = "";
var link = document.getElementById('gotoURL');
var link1 = document.getElementById('gotoURL1');
link1.innerHTML = url ? initial+url+extension : '' ;
link1.href = initial+url+extension;
link.href = initial+url+extension;
}
```

```html
   
    <body background="1.jpg">
        
<h1><font><b><i><font face="helvetica">Refer & Earn</font></h1>
        </b>
        </i>
<font><font face="helvetica">



<FORM name="something" action="#">

<fieldset>
<legend><b> Your Referral URL </b></legend>
<font><font color="yellow"><b><i> Enter your mobile number and then copy the link and share.</font>
        </b>
        </i>
        <br>
        <INPUT type="text" name="url" value="" onkeyup="goToPage(this.value)">
        </FORM>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <fieldset><font><font color="white"><br> Your Unique Referral Link:  <a href="" id="gotoURL1"></a></font>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
<a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="Take a look at this awesome website:" id="gotoURL">Share</a>
```